# Java compilation error: switch on enum

Tags: java, enums

I came across a very weird error that I just can't figure out how to solve.

A project, that compiles just fine on Windows, doesn't compile on Linux with the following error:

```
Cannot switch on a value of type AClass.Bbb. Only convertible int values, strings or enum variables are permitted
```

, even though the stated type **is** an enum.

The code of the class is something along these lines: 

`public class AClass {
    private enum Bbb {
        ONE,
        TWO;
    }
    public void aMethod(List<Bbb> arg) {
        for (Bbb en : arg) {
            switch (en) {
                ....
            }
        }
    }
}`

The `en` in `switch(en)` is underlined, with the error notification stated above.

Has anyone else had it? Is there a way to solve this?

*UPD* Java version:

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: how about the Java versions on these machines?

Comment: The error says value of type `Aaa.Bbb`. Is it a typo, or are you importing a different Bbb?

Comment: check your imports, you are using wrong imports for Bbb, Bbb shouldn't be in your import list.

Comment: @trogdor It is a typo, I will fix it

Comment: @Juvanis added the java version info into the post.

Answer (score 3):

The problem should go away if u r using JDK1.7 .Try following the below steps and see

1. Open the project properties
2. Click on "Java Compiler"
3. Checkmark "Enable project specific settings"
4. Set all of the drop down menus to 1.7
5. Hit ok
6. Clean the project to trigger a rebuild

If u do below , then the problem reappears.

1. Open the project properties
2. Click on "Java Compiler"
3. Clear "Enable project specific settings"
4. Hit ok
5. Clean the project to trigger a rebuild (it will rebuild automatically)

Here's what I see if I do the following...

1. Open the project properties
2. Click on "Java Compiler"
3. Click on "Configure Workspace Settings"
4. I see that the "Compiler compliance level" = 1.7
5. I see that "Use default compliance settings" is checked.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 2):

I have tried your code

```
public class AClass {
     enum Bbb {
        ONE,
        TWO;
    }
    public void aMethod(List<Bbb> arg) {
        for (Bbb en : arg) {
            switch (en) {

                case ONE: System.out.println("ONE");break;
                case TWO: System.out.println("TWO");break;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Bbb> list = new ArrayList<Bbb>();
        list.add(Bbb.ONE);
        list.add(Bbb.TWO);

        new AClass().aMethod(list);
    }
}
```

It is working fine.
I dont know the pros and cons of passing argument like this `List<Bbb> arg` but atleast it is not error as much as i know in java 7

Comment: I know it should work, and it works on other machines, but not on this one.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether it is windows/linux related issue. But

From jdk5 onwards you can use `enum` in switch case and from jdk7 you can use String in switch case. While using `enum` in switch make sure that:

1. you are using jdk5 and later
2. All the labels used in your switch must be a valid `enum` object inside
   your enum being used in switch.

In java enum is implemented through class concept(Each n every `enum` in java extends to `Enum` class that is an `abstract` class and direct sub class of `Object` class). So while creating enum like

```
 public enum Bbb {
        ONE,
        TWO;
    }
```

It will internally meant

```
public static final Bbb ONE=new Bbb();
public static final Bbb TWO=new Bbb();
```

Means all your defined `enum` objects are public, final and static objects of defined `enum` class. If you are using something else as `switch label`, it will give a compile time error.

For each `enum` in java, `super class` `Enum` is `final` and all `enum` classes are internally implemented as `final`. So `inheritance` can not be used for `enum` in java. Means we are not allowed to use anything else in `switch labels` except our own class `enum` objects(Not even subclass objects, because `enum` class can't be `inherited` further)